# inserting an image to excel sheet doesnt work

Tags: c#, winforms, image, excel, insert

i'm trying to insert an image to excel sheet like below.

```
Image img = Image.FromFile("test.jpg");
sheet.get_Range("A1").set_Item(1,1,img);
```

but when excel opens in A1 cell there is not any picture,
but there is only this result:**System.Drawing.Bitmap**
So what is the problem, how can i solve it.
And Second Question is:
how to insert to excel if my pictures are located in database. and i dont want to save them to computer for inserting to the excel?
[WinForm]

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this:

object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
Excel.Range picPosition = sheet.get_Range("A1"); // retrieve the range for picture insert
Excel.Pictures p = yourWorksheet.Pictures(missing) as Excel.Pictures;
Excel.Picture pic = null;
pic = p.Insert(yourImageFilePath, missing);
pic.Left = Convert.ToDouble(picRange.Left);
pic.Top = picRange.Top;
pic.Placement = // Can be any of Excel.XlPlacement.XYZ value
```

Comment: what if my image located in the database and i dont want to save this image to the harddisk. how can i insert an image to excel directly without saving it?

Comment: hi, have you try it with an image on hard disk?

Comment: see ProcessRequest in this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33310/C-Save-and-Load-Image-from-Database

Comment: yes i have tried, and works, but i have more than 500 pictures in the table. i dont want every time to save them to computer and after that insert to excel.

Comment: so the first question was answered (thank to mark it). for the second question you will get a stream from database (see url codeproject) and load this stream in an image (Image.FromStream)

Comment: i am very very sorry Mr Hassan. Could you show it on the code, please?

Comment: @namco Please split up your questions. And put error messages in the answer where you get them...

Answer (score 1):

```
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader rdr = null;
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = null;
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand selcmd = null;
            try
            {
              conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
            (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
            ["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
//here set your query to get image from databse
              selcmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
            ("select pic1 from msg where msgid=" + 
            context.Request.QueryString["imgid"], conn);
              conn.Open();
              rdr = selcmd.ExecuteReader();
              while (rdr.Read())
              {
                byte[] YourImagebytearray = ((byte[])rdr["pic1"]);
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                var newImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
                stream.Dispose();
              }
              if (rdr != null)
                rdr.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
              if (conn != null)
                  conn.Close();
            }
```

Comment: thanks, i know how to convert bytestream to an image, but i want to know how to insert this image to excel without saving it to computer. Could you show me that code please?

Comment: i have wrote your code but it gives an error - 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet.Pictures(object)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context.

Comment: Guys, this is a chameleon question and this answer has nothing to do with the specific question.

Comment: I am agree with you so thank namco to set another question i will move this answer into it.Fort this question thank to mark my answer as ok because namco you said "yes i have tried, and works"

Comment: Yes works when images are stored in the computer. This is Ok. But i said that i dont want to save the images to the computer. i want to select images from db and insert them to excel worksheet without saving them to computer every time.

Comment: i understand but it is a second question ... your question was inserting an image to excel sheet doesnt work

Comment: if somebody search an answer she/he will search on title and the second question you want will be how get excel picture from a stream

Comment: Ok u are right. I am sorry Mr. Hassan. i have changed the question body. Could you answer to my second question please?